# Make VBA wait until SQL query loaded

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am having a problem in Excel, I am importing data using SQL and then editting some of that data however the problem I am having is that the VB code continues to run before the data from SQL is loaded into Excel, causing lots of errors in the data.

This is my code to import the data

```
 sqlstring1 = "SELECT [compnumber],[mapcode],[amount],[reportd],[reportm],[reporty]  FROM [Mergent].[dbo].[Annual]" & _
    "WHERE Compnumber = '" & Sheets("list").Cells(i, 1).Value & "';"
    connstring = _
    "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=ANDY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;UID=Andy;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=Mergent"
    With Sheets("data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Sheets("data").Range("a1"), Sql:=sqlstring1)
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery = False
    End With
```

I need to somehow make VBA wait until its loaded. The code is looping through thousands of SQL queries of varying sizes so doing a simple 'wait 10 seconds' isn't really good enough and would add significant time to run the code.

Is there any way to get VBA to wait until the query is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your query in the background. Try compiling your code.

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery = False
```

You have a variable, `BackgroundQuery`, which is not defined.

They way to use named parameters is to use `:=` not `=`

try

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery := False
```

Comment: Ah thanks that seemed to make it work. I copied the code off the net so didn't realise that := was a problem